# R Error: new columns would leave holes after existing columns; How to solve this?

Tags: r

I try to run my code but always receive the following error message:

> `` Fehler in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = list(`NOVN SW Equity PX_LAST` = c(6.54,  :  new columns would leave holes after existing columns ``

My code looks as following

```
library(tidyverse)
Daten_bloomberg <- read_excel("~/Desktop/master thesis topics/Data for R/Daten_bloomberg.xlsx", na = "NA")
Event <- read_excel("~/Desktop/master thesis topics/Data for R/Event.xlsx", col_types = c("numeric", "text"))
Daten_bloomberg <- as.data.frame(sapply(Daten_bloomberg, as.numeric)) 
Daten_bloomberg[is.na(Daten_bloomberg)] <- NA

Data_last_price <- data.frame(Data1 = rep(1,7875) )

for (i in 1:133) {
  EventTicker <-  as.character(Event[i,2])
  EventTicker1 <- paste(as.character(Event[i,2]) , "PX_Last") 
  Data1 <- select(Daten_bloomberg , contains(EventTicker1))
  Data_last_price[,i] <- rep(Data1,1)
}
```

With that Code I basically try to make a new dataframe with columns containing the ticker and the string PX_Last. Daten_bloomberg contains 7875 rows and 884 variables. Event contains 133 observations and two variables.

However, always when I run this loop the above error message is occuring and the loop stops at position 87. I guess the problem is that the columns in the Dataset Daten_bloomberg contains a lot of NA Values. But I do not know how i can solve that problem. Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright we have a few things to tackle here.

First, welcome to SO, and your code is not reproducible, as it is lacking an example dataset. You can also leave out `rep(data1, 1)` as `rep(x, 1) == x`.

Next it is incredible that you have obtained your specific error, meaning I had to dig into the source code to find it as I've never seen it in the 6 years of my R experience. And it might not be easy to see, but your error is not from iteration 87 but iteration 86.

Lets illustrate with a reproducible example (notice the names at first).

```
names(mtcars)
[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
library(tidyverse)
mtcars2 <- mtcars
newcols <- c("I'm not column", "cyl") # <= one column exist, one does not
for(i in seq_along(newcols)){
  mtcars[, ncol(mtcars) + i] <- select(mtcars2, contains(newcols[i]))
}
print(i) 
[1] 2
```

Oh notice how it threw an error on `cyl` (i = 2), so the most obvious thought is "there's something wrong with my `cyl` column". But lets look at mtcars for a moment

```
names(mtcars)
[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

Oh.. There's no new column for `"I'm not a column"` (should be named `"V1"`), which I tried to place into position 12. Next we try to place `cyl` into position 13, but there is no column 12, so `[<-.data.frame` tries to create column 12, but as we haven't supplied any value for this column, it throws an error, as seem in the smaller example below:

```
mtcars[, 13] <- mtcars2$cyl
```

So in short, for your specific case running the code below should result in the last line being printed (which is your error)

```
i <- 86
EventTicker <-  as.character(Event[i,2])
EventTicker1 <- paste(as.character(Event[i,2]) , "PX_Last") 
Data1 <- select(Daten_bloomberg , contains(EventTicker1))
nrow(Data1)
[1] 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed Response Oliver. I see the issue is located in the search function. Namely, that the column did not exist for which i searched for. By deleting that row in my event data the code worked well. Thank you very much again also for the improvement comment on my code, implemented that as well.

Comment: My pleasure. It was a curious and weird error, so I am glad to have seen it. And one that I find very unintuitive. Remember to upvote if you found the answer helpful/good and mark the answer as "the answer" by hitting the checkmark in the top-left of the answer itself. We all do this for the points, and spend our free time on helping out, so the points is our incentive to continue doing so! :-) Also it increases the questions visibility for others looking for answers to similar questions in the future. :-)